# Why one code is giving tle while I think the other one which is same is only taking 15ms in online coding platform

Tags: c++, matrix, dynamic-programming

**This is the code which is giving tle. I am using a 3d matrix for solving a problem through memoization.**

```
class Solution {
    public:
        
         int dp[1001][2][101];
        
         int find(vector<int> nums, int k, int i, bool flag){
           if(i>=nums.size() || k==0)return 0;
           if(dp[i][flag][k]!=-1)return dp[i][flag][k];
             
           if(flag){
               return dp[i][flag][k]=max(-nums[i]+find(nums, k, i+1, !flag), find(nums, k, i+1, flag));
           }
             else{
                 return dp[i][flag][k]=max(nums[i]+find(nums, k-1, i+1, !flag), find(nums, k, i+1, flag));
             }
        }
        int maxProfit(int k, vector<int>& prices) {
            if(2*k>prices.size()){
                int res = 0;
                for (int i = 1; i < prices.size(); i++) {
                    res += max(0, prices[i] - prices[i - 1]);
                }
                return res;
            }
           memset(dp, -1, sizeof(dp));
           return find(prices, k, 0, 1);
        }
    };
```

**While this is the code which is only taking 15ms time. is getting accepted.**

```
class Solution {
public:
   int find(vector<int> &prices,int ind,bool buy,int c,int k,vector<vector<vector<int>>> &memo)
    {   
        if(ind>=prices.size()||c>=k) return 0; //counter
        
        else if(memo[ind][buy][c]!=-1) return memo[ind][buy][c];
         
        if(buy) 
        {
        return memo[ind][buy][c]=max(-prices[ind]+find(prices,ind+1,!buy,c,k,memo),find(prices,ind+1,buy,c,k,memo));
        }
        else  
        {
        return memo[ind][buy][c]=max(prices[ind]+find(prices,ind+1,!buy,c+1,k,memo),find(prices,ind+1,buy,c,k,memo));
        }
        
    }
    int maxProfit(int k, vector<int>& prices) {
        if (2 * k > prices.size()) {
             int res = 0;
             for (int i = 1; i < prices.size(); i++) {
                 res += max(0, prices[i] - prices[i - 1]);
             }
             return res;
         }
        
        vector<vector<vector<int>>> memo(prices.size()+1,vector<vector<int>>(2,vector<int>(k+1,-1)));
        return find(prices,0,1,0,k,memo); 
    }
};
```

**While both are doing the same job but the first one is getting tle while the other one is getting accepted with great time complexity. I want to know the reason. BTW the question is Best time to Buy or Sell stock 4.**

Comment: How this is related to `rcpp`?

Comment: `int dp[1001][2][101];` -- Don't declare gigantic local arrays like this.  The proper way to do this is to use a container class, such as `std::vector`.  You are risking blowing out the stack memory with declarations like this.

Comment: You mean *besides* the blatant difference passing the lead argument (the vector) to `find` by reference vs pass by value? That thing is recursing a *ton* and considering that container is never actually modified, that is a tremendous amount of data copying for absolutely no reason.

Comment: @WhozCraig Though by passing through refrence descrease the time complexity to 486ms but still there is a huge difference. I want to know why there is so much diference.

Comment: @WhozCraig And of course this time I used vector and passed through reference.

Comment: Profile both programs and figure out why yours is slow

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn the basics of debugging.

First, you need to learn *commenting*. Each function needs a comment that specifies *precisely* what the function is supposed to do. Especially here, where at least one function doesn’t do what it’s supposed to do, so I can’t look at the source code.

Then debugging. Put some variables static long count1, count2, etc. into your code. At strategic places, increment those variables and print them. Then you know how often which steps are executed. If one code executes a lot more steps you can figure out why that is.

Comment: "First, you need to learn commenting. Each function needs a comment that specifies precisely what the function is supposed to do." I disagree. This is what a proper function name is for. No need for comments that are just redundant.